# How to automatically delete database record using Laravel Queues?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am working with laravel 5.6 and I need  delete a records which old than 15 days from now from **vehicles** table daily. I am workin in windows 7 and localhost is WAMP. 
I need following like code to run,

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(15))->get();

foreach ($vechicles as $vehicle) {
    $vehicle->delete();
}
```

So, My first question is may I do such as activity using laravel Queues? and if it is so, How to do this?

Comment: you need task scheduling for automatic action. see docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling

Comment: Also, as a small optimization, you might want to delete the records with a single query: `Vehicle::where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(15))->delete();`

Comment: I do not use task sheduling. I like to Queues if it can do this?

Comment: @AndriusRimkus can I use Queues to do this. because I am new to this task?

Comment: Of course you can create a small background job for this and create some endpoint to trigger job dispatching. The syntax is straightforward: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#creating-jobs

Comment: @AndriusRimkus can you post some example codes or tutorials here except laravel documents?